# Wget can't download a complete file in ubuntu

Tags: http, ubuntu-14.04, wget, content-length

I was using `wget` to download a file,like this:

`wget link/file.zip`

the `file.zip` was about 100M, but I just receive 5552B:
[image]

and whatever I downloaded(large than 5552B, from some other hosts), I just receive 5552B!
The HTTP response header content-length was 5552B too!
I was using Ubuntu14.04, Are there some network configurations to solve this problem?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: There's a lot of characters in your URL that is interpreted by the shell (such as the & character). Place your entire URL inside single quotes: `wget 'http://sdlc..'`  and try again.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work for me. Actually, I was using java code to download file,like this:`        URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(this.remoteFileUrl).openConnection();
        System.out.println("contentlength="+urlConnection.getContentLength());`
the 'contentlength' is still 5552B!

Comment: Then look inside the downloaded file, it might be an HTML page telling you that you forgot to accept the Terms of Use, or a captcha or anything else preventing an automated download.

Comment: I move to another machine which is also Ubuntu14.04, and download the same link, `wget` works perfectly! So it doesn't prevent automated downloading.
Thanks a lot!